# Complete list not getting stored

Tags: android, android-listview, android-adapter

While storing the list in adapter only one item is getting stored inside list while my list size is 7.Log returns the size of list as 7  but returns only one item name..There is no crash or no exception in log.Any idea why my complete list not getting stored?

```
SqlAdapter adapter;        

    private void updateStoreFollow(List<Follow> followers,String type)
            {

                Follow tempFollow = new Follow();
                tempFollow.setIsfollow(type);
                adapter.delete(tempFollow);
        Log.e("bhuvnesh","size"+followers.size());
                for (Follow v:followers)
                {
                    Log.e("name","name"+v.getName());
                    v.setIsfollow(type);

                    adapter.store(v);

                }

            }
```

Log

```
size7
namenametapan
```

Comment: are you adding or removing items after setAdapter(adapter)?

Comment: what is SqlAdapter? Could you post a code of it?